# What are SMITrigger, SMIBool, SMINumber, SMIInput used for in rive animation tool?

Tags: flutter, rive

I am learning flutter with rive.

Ifound a tutorial app and there is:
success = controller.findInput('Check') as SMITrigger;
As far as I understand and saw in the state machine editor, it is the condition name of a transition between 2 states.
After we can do success.fire() to trigger the animation.
But what are SMIBool, SMINumber, SMIInput?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

These class are used to control the artBoard animation's>> AnimationController>>  `inputs` sections with flutter.

Image from Rive editor.

[image]

**SMITrigger**: You can think this as a bool which reset to false itself automatically. (e.g. Pressing a key on keyboard which move up once we redirect to another key).  This class used to read and create instance of `Trigger` input.

**SMIBool**:  This is used to get and used to control  `Bool` input.

**SMINumber**:  You read and control `Number` input.

**SMIInput**: State Machine Instance Input, you can read any of them. Like   `SMIInput<double>` reading for bool which can be replaced with `SMIBool`.

Find more about [rive](https://pub.dev/documentation/rive/latest/rive/rive-library.html) and [my rive_state_machine_example](https://github.com/yeasin50/Rive_state_machine_example).

Comment: Wow, thank you for this usefull answer. Have a nice day!